# Entity Framework 6 - How to Update Models from Database - Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations, ef-database-first

I have an app that is designed using EF 6 database first. When I right click in my EDMX file and click 'Update model From database' the following error occurs:

[image]
[image]

How do I solve this? Re creating the db is not an option.

I tried adding a new table to the DB model using EF 6 database first - Received an error

Comment: Which part of "An entry with the same key already exists" do you not understand?  You have a key field/column and you are trying to save a new entity with a duplicate key to the one that already exists in the database.

Comment: Thats the issue - An entry with the same key does not exist @Neil

Comment: @Neil OP seems to get that error when updating the model, not the database entries